# ParametricPlot3D doesn't appear

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Here I have one simple system solvable with NDSolve. I don't know why ParametricPlot3D doesn't present trajectory in space. I have solutions for x[t], y[t] and z[t]

```
  ss = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -1^2*((1 + 1) x[t])/
  Abs[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)]^(3/2), 
 y''[t] == -1^2*((1 + 1) y[t])/Abs[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)]^(3/
  2), z''[t] == -1^2*((1 + 1) z[t])/
  Abs[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)]^(3/2), x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
z'[0] == 0, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 10, z[0] == 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 
1.2}];

 ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[x[t] /. ss], Evaluate[y[t] /. ss], 
 Evaluate[z[t] /. ss]}, {t, 0, 1.2}]

Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. ss], {t, 0, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. ss], {t, 0, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] /. ss], {t, 0, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: You need to use `ss = First@NDSolve[..]` or `x[t] /. First[ss]` etc. Or `Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. ss]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made (at least) two mistakes in your `ParametricPlot3D` call. First let me give you a solution. When you have *Mathematica* version 9, the probably easiest method is to use `NDSolveValue` which spares you the extraction of the solution from rules:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{x''[
      t] == -1^2*((1 + 1) x[t])/Abs[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)]^(3/2),
     y''[t] == -1^2*((1 + 1) y[t])/
       Abs[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)]^(3/2), 
    z''[t] == -1^2*((1 + 1) z[t])/
       Abs[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)]^(3/2), x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
    z'[0] == 0, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 10, z[0] == 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 
    1.2}];

ParametricPlot3D[Through[sol[t]], {t, 0, 1.2}]
```

Please look at `sol` to see that you get a list of pure functions. `Through` is very handy here, because it transforms an expression `{x,y,z}[t]` into `{x[t],y[t],z[t]}`.

When you want to stick with your `NDSolve` call, than you have to use your solution `ss` in the following way

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. ss], {t, 0, 1.2}]
```

Let me explain your two mistakes. First, although the above works, please check the output of `NDSolve` to see, that you get a *list of a list* as result. You should get rid of one level by using `First` as suggested by Michael in his comment.

The second issue is quite interesting and maybe not as easy to understand. Your call looked like

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[x[t] /. ss],...},..]
```

You used `Evaluate` with good intention, but it has no effect if it is not *the `Head` of the argument*. The head of your argument here is `List`. Let's make a very small example function

```
Attributes[f] = {HoldAll};
f[x_] := ToString[Unevaluated[x]]
```

`f` does not evaluate its argument and it prints it in unevaluated form. Therefore, `f[1+1]` results in `"1+1"`, although usual functions would first evaluated the argument to 2. This is exactly the same behavior that `ParametricPlot3D` has. Now you want to evaluate the `1+1` before printing it and you try

```
f[Evaluate[1 + 1]]

(* "2" *)
```

and get 2 as expected. The very important thing is, that this only works as long `Evaluate` appears as head of the argument. You can check this by trying

```
f[{1 + 1, Evaluate[1 + 1]}]

(* {1 + 1, Evaluate[1 + 1]} *)
```

or by reading more about the main evaluation loop of *Mathematica*.

Conclusion is: You were absolutely right to use `Evaluate` to evaluated the argument because `ParametricPlot3D` holds its arguments but `Evaluate` needs to appear as head of the argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for full and helpful answer