# Tooltip and table in plot

Tags: plotting, tooltip

```
Plot[Tooltip@{1.` k^2, 1.2` k^2, 1.4` k^2, 1.6` k^2, 1.8` k^2, 2.` k^2}, {k, -2, 2}]
```

gives

[image]

But why does

```
Plot[Tooltip@Evaluate@Table[a k^2, {a, 1, 2, 0.2}], {k, -2, 2}]
```

give

[image]
with no color difference?

Comment: `Evaluate` has to be right after `Plot`. Try `Plot[Evaluate@Tooltip@Table[a k^2, {a, 1, 2, 0.2}], {k, -2, 2}]`.

Comment: Related: [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate), [the second half of this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21447/parametricplot3d-doesnt-appear/21449#21449), and perhaps [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. But I still don't get it. In the first example, I use Tooltip@List in Plot, it works well. In the second example, I use "Evaluate" before "Table" in order to turn the "Table" expr into a list first, because I know "Plot" will consider the "Table" as a single entity without "Evaluate", So I think it should be the same as the first example with "Evaluate". But it is not. And you proposed to let the "Evaluate" before "Tooltip", then it works! Wow, I still don't know why.

Comment: @matheorem When you pinned down the error, you always have to check the doc's of `Evaluate` again. [Under Details it clearly says:](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html) "Evaluate only overrides HoldFirst, etc. attributes when it appears directly as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held". Therefore, `Evaluate` has always be the most outwards function of an argument: `f[Evaluate[...],...]`.

Comment: @matheorem It takes a while to get used to the fact that some *Mathematica* commands hold (keep unevaluated) some or all of the arguments, and `Evaluate` overrides it.  `Evaluate@Tooltip@Table...` evaluates to `Tooltip@List...` before being passed to `Plot`.  I don't know what else to add to halirutan's explanation.